# M2 - Difference between ScopeInterface SCOPE_STORE and SCOPE_STORES

Tags: magento2, configuration, core-config-data, scope, scopeinterface

I understand that there are websites, stores within websites, and store views within a store. However, one thing I've never understood is the difference between `ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE` and `ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORES`

What is the difference? And when would you use them for reading/writing config values?